# How to update two values in a single column at a time

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a table

```
STOCK_ITEM (id number (2), 
            item varchar2 (20), 
            purchase_date date, 
            quantity number (2))
```

having list of items like laptop, desktop, telephone, mobile, tv and their description.

We have to write an update query which updates laptop to desktop and desktop to laptop.

How can I acheive this?

Following are the sample data:

```
insert into stock_item values (1,'laptop','01/17',4);
insert into stock_item values (2,'desktop','02/17',3);
insert into stock_item values (3,'laptop','03/17',2);
insert into stock_item values (4,'tv','11/17',6);
insert into stock_item values (5,'fridge','07/17',5);
insert into stock_item values (6,'desktop','05/17',9);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: you probably need a case expression.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Frankly, i have tried normal update query which is not working here obviously... @boneist where should I use case in update....in where clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is working with 1 update with decode values:

```
update STOCK_ITEM set ITEM=decode(ITEM,'laptop', 'desktop','desktop', 'laptop', ITEM);
```

after update laptop records will be replaced with desktop and the opposite.

Comment: `laptop` and `desktop` are data values not column names

Comment: for the uninitiated `decode()` is Oracle's original implementation of a switch function. It is similar to `case()` but can only offer equality tests.

Answer (score 2):

I would write the update statement something like:

```
update stock_item
set item = case lower(item)
                when 'laptop' then 'desktop'
                when 'desktop' then 'laptop'
           end
where lower(item) in ('laptop', 'desktop');
```

That way, you're only updating the rows that need changing, and a case expression is clearer in intent than a decode, making it easier to read and maintain.

I've used the lower function to ensure that all items that are laptops or desktops (regardless of case, e.g. LAPTOP, LaPtOp, Laptop, etc) would be updated.

Comment: thanks much boneist. I have one more q realated to same table. Due to space constraint,user has put limited entries in the table. For example, if we see first row with id=1, laptop quantity=4 for month 01/17,its next entry is in 3rd row with id=3 and quantity=2, that means from 01/17 till 03/17 the stock quantity was 4 only.So, we need to write a query which fetch correct result of 4 when date=02/17

Comment: You should ask that as a separate question. One way would be to generate an end date by using the lead() analytic function, and then you could use that in your query. If you're unfamiliar with analytic functions, there is plenty of information available out there; I highly recommend you google it and have a go at working out your select statement before raising a new question on here.

Comment: @KhushbooMantri - as Boneist said, that's a different and unrelated question which should be posted separately. I don't see what the problem is though: in the WHERE condition, filter for the rows where the date is <= <your date input> and then sum. You shouldn't need a SO question for something that basic.

Comment: Sorry guys i will take care next time.
@boneist: thanks for the clue of lead function.I dint know about this. I cracked the query :)